# Bamboo will not create .IPA files using either xbuild or mdtool

Tags: ios, bamboo, ipa

I am trying to create an IPA file from Bamboo by doing this:  Firstly I will checkout the default repository, then clone a devops repository, then have a nuget restore task.  All of these tasks work perfectly fine but it is the Build for iOS task which is where I create my .IPA file is were I am having the problems. Firstly I am using a command task and the files are being build on a mac-agent(needed to create the .IPA file).

I have tried this two different ways, both ways have different outcomes but basically it is not what I expect to happen.  The first way I tried was to use **mdtool** as the executable which worked like this:

```
-v build -t:build -p:CustomerApp.iOS *-c:Release|iPhone* CustomerApp.sln
```

This task will build but the .IPA file will not be created and the log file just says Build for iOS succeeded so I do not know what the problem is for that.  The second way that I tried was to use **xbuild** as the executable which I did it like this:

```
xbuild /p:Configuration=AppStore /p:Platform=iPhone /p:BuildIpa=true /target:Build CustomerApp.sln
```

And also tried changing the `/p:Configuration=AppStore` to `/p:Configuration=Release`

But both of these responses will return the error

```
MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0004: Too many project files specified
```

Note that I know it says error **MSBUILD0004** but I am not calling the error the **xbuild** executable is called with the path: */usr/local/bin/xbuild* likewise the **mdtool** is being called successfully through the path: */Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Conents/MacOS/mdtool* and I have checked that the files exist through the terminal.

What is the reason that the mdtool and xbuild will not create the .IPA file?  From what I have seen online it was mainly to do with applications that were not up to date but mine are as shown by the log here:

```
Already up-to-date.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from '/usr/local/Cellar/mono/4.6.2.7/lib/mono/4.5'.
All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.
```

Bamboo is creating a folder which is called MOB-CUSAPP9-JOB1. This is where I want to generate the IPA file from but using that still gives me the error above when using the xbuild way, inside the folder when it is generated it has a file called the CustomerApp.sln which I also tried but got the error as well. Inside the MOB-CUSAPP9-JOB1 files that get created are Mobile.Core.iOS and CustomerApp.iOS I have tried to use all of these and get the same error, I have even tried the whole directory to this but /users/dev/bamboo/etc/MOB-CUSAPP9-JOB1 but got the same result.

Here is an image of the folder that bamboo builds:
[image]

Comment: For `xbuild` change the `CustomerApp.sln` to a specific project that you want to build, because `xbuild`/`msbuild` uses the project as an entry point to trigger the build for the solution based upon the `Configuration` & `Platform` definition. That should solve that issue, and if you encounter another issue were it states that you do not have an `OutputPath` defined (even if the project does have one defined), then you might have to include this for the `xbuild` parameters: `/p:OutputPath="Your path here"`

Comment: I have been still having an issue though with `xbuild` not generating an IPA though, so if it works for you, please let me know.

Comment: If you want your IPA to be generated to a different location use this `xbuild` parameter: `/p:IpaPackageDir="Your path here"` that should ensure that the IPA is generated at the MOB-CUSAPP9-JOB1 folder that you desire. You are still getting the `MSBUILD: error MSBUILD0004: Too many project files specified` error when you specified a specific project like this: `xbuild /p:Configuration=AppStore /p:Platform=iPhone /p:BuildIpa=true /target:Build CustomerApp.iOS`? Check to see if your `CustomerApp.iOS.proj` (or what ever project you are building) file contains the `AppStore|iPhone` configuration.

Comment: @Ckrempp I added a folder of what bamboo creates, which target should I choose, I thought it would have been the CustomerApp.sln but anything I tried didn't work.  I added the ipapackagedir but got the same error message

Comment: I also tried in the CustomerApp.iOS folder using the CustomerApp.iOS.csproj but got the same result

Comment: My apologies I mistyped it should be something like this, try this: `xbuild /p:Configuration=AppStore /p:Platform=iPhone /p:BuildIpa=true /target:Build CustomerApp.iOS.csproj`, also did you check to ensure that your csproj file contains the `AppStore|iPhone` configuration?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't at the moment

Comment: That is the first problem, you need to have something like this in your csproj file: `  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'AppStore|iPhone' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\AppStore</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>False</ConsolePause>
    <MtouchArch>ARMv7, ARM64</MtouchArch>
  </PropertyGroup>`, also make sure that your solution file has that configuration.

Comment: I don't see how I can do this though because I only get the folder from the bamboo build so if I changed it it would just undo it anyway after another build.

Comment: I have not worked with bamboo, but that is the first step to fixing the problem is getting the correct configuration into the csproj file.